# Laravel 5 problems with making pdf

Tags: laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using Laravel 5 and Nitmedia's wkhtml2pdf package to create PDFs.
I'm on Linux Debian 8.2 (jessie) and PHP 5.6.14, and I can't really change/customize it because it's a company server.

I'm having 2 problems (maybe they're related).

First one is, when I make the PDF file I can't set bottom margin to 0, I always have 1-2 pixels whitespace on the bottom of the document. 
Here's the pic:
[image: PDF Screenshot]

See the whitespace 1-2px wide below blue border? That's whats bothering me.

Here are my options for page:

```php
PDF::setOptions('-T 0mm -B 0mm -L 0mm -R 0mm');
PDF::setPageSize('A4');
PDF::setOrientation('landscape');
PDF::setOutputMode('F');
```

I tried everything, but with no success.

Also when I print that file my bottom border overflow to 2nd page.

Here's my CSS code:

```css
html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    border: 5px solid #1565c0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div.content {
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: url('background_img.png');
    background-size: 50%;
    background-position: 220px 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px 37px 0px;
}
```

How can I make my PDFs full size (no margins)? And why my print version differs from the PDF I've made? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: the best way i found to generate PDF-s is to install xvfb-run create and save html and then 

 $process = new Process( 'xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf ' . $html . ' ' . $pdf );
        $process->run();

Process is from http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: i've fixed above problem by setting page size in mm's...thanks anyway